# bx slider doesn't work in chrome

Tags: php, html, bxslider

```
------this code doesn't work in chrome but works in Mozilla---------
<div class="slide_data">
    <strong><?PHP echo $city; ?></strong>  
    <img src="<?PHP echo $imgsrc; ?>" alt="Image Not available"></img> 
    <img src="images/ribbon-featured.png" class="feature"/>  
</div> 
--------this code works in chrome and mozila-----
<div class="slide_data">
    <strong><?PHP echo $city; ?></strong>  
    <img src="img/phpto.jpg" alt="Image Not available"></img> 
    <img src="images/ribbon-featured.png" class="feature"/>  
</div>
  ------------I want the first one to work on both---------
```

> I am changing the src of the img tag using a php variable. Actually this was working well 15 days ago but I don't know what happens now.Check the site eestate.in----in chrome and Mozilla

Comment: Can you please `var_dump($imgsrc)` and paste result on your question.

Comment: `<?php var_dump($imgsrc) ?>` put this code under your slider and show us what is result.

Comment: no this in hot working.

Comment: <?php var_dump($imgsrc) ?> nothing happens with this code

Comment: it gives the output:

Comment: string(40) "images/property_images/54e31f51a3857.jpg"

Comment: Are you sure image is exists on the path?

Comment: yes.because it works fine in mozila you check na the site "eestate,in" in chrome and mozila